# Yii Clistview only print once

Tags: yii, frameworks, clistview

I want to echo a div only once in a Clistview, the items are order by status, so, i want to print status 1 -> all the items, and then status 2 -> all the items with that status, I tried viewData, but I dont know how to change the value of the flag.

INDEX VIEW:

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <?php 
            $activos_flag = 1;
            $inactivos_flag = 1;
        ?>
        <?php 
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CListView', array(
                'id'=>'incs',
                'summaryText'=>'',
                'dataProvider'=>$dataProviderInc,
                'itemView'=>'_incidencias',
                'viewData'=> array('activo'=> $activos_flag,'inactivo'=>$inactivos_flag),
            ));
        ?>
    </div>
```

_INCIDENCIAS VIEW:

```
<?php 
    if ($data->activo == 1 and $data->incidencia_estado == 1){
        echo ('<label class="incidencias">ACTIVOS</label>');
        $data->activo = 0;
    }
    if ($data->inactivo == 1 and $data->incidencia_estado == 0){
        echo ('<label class="incidencias">INACTIVOS</label>');
        $data->inactivo = 0;
    }
?>
```

Comment: which flags you are talking about? and why do you want to change th flags?

Comment: because i only want to echo the label "activos" once, at the beginning of the clistview and the label "inactivos" once when "activos" has ended.

Comment: actually i am confused about your question. Correct me if i am wrong. You want to display label depending upon the value of the flags?

Comment: also elaborate more your scenario that what do you want to do. I cant get you from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value not from the array `$data` (`$data->inactivo`) but directly from a variable `$inactivo`. But in any case, at each iteration, the value of these variables will again be equal to `1`. In this case, you can use the following approach:
Before widget declaration:

```
Yii::app()->params['activos_flag']=1;
Yii::app()->params['inactivos_flag']=1;
```

and in parial view:

```
if ( Yii::app()->params['activos_flag'] == 1 ){
    echo ('<label class="incidencias">ACTIVOS</label>');
    Yii::app()->params['activos_flag'] = 0;
}
if ( Yii::app()->params['inactivos_flag'] == 1 ){
    echo ('<label class="incidencias">INACTIVOS</label>');
    Yii::app()->params['inactivos_flag'] = 0;
}
```